# Laravel 5 melhorar filtro

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5

Eu criei um filtro na minha view index, quando coloco algo dentro de um dos inputs dos filtro entra nos ifs mas acho que não está bom desta forma, alguém sabe de alguma forma melhor?

```
public function index()
{
    $usuariosFiltro = null;
    $estadoFiltro = null;
    $cidadeFiltro = null;
    $statusFiltro = null;

    if(Input::has('Usuario_nome'))
    {
        $usuariosFiltro = Input::get('Usuario_nome');
    }

    if(Input::has('Usuario_cidade'))
    {
        $cidadeFiltro = Input::get('Usuario_cidade');
    }

    if(Input::has('Usuario_status'))
    {
        $statusFiltro = Input::get('Usuario_status');
    }

    $usuarios = Usuario::filtrarUsuario($usuariosFiltro)->filtrarCidade($cidadeFiltro)->filtrarStatus($statusFiltro)->paginate();

    $estados = Estado::orderBy('uf')->lists('uf', 'est_id');

    return view('usuarios.index', compact('usuarios', 'estados'));
}
```

Comment: Poste seus models Usuario e Estado. Existem formas muito melhores diferente da sua resposta atual.

Comment: Você está programando um Laravel dentro do Laravel.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Utilizar 'WHERE' se valor for diferente de 'NULL' num sistema de pesquisa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127107/utilizar-where-se-valor-for-diferente-de-null-num-sistema-de-pesquisa)

Comment: Outra Possível duplicada [Como Filtrar Vários Campos na Consulta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129873/como-filtrar-v%C3%A1rios-campos-na-consulta)

Answer (score -1):

Fiz de uma forma melhor:

```
public function index()
{
    $usuariosBuilder = new Usuario();

    if(Input::has('Usuario_nome'))
    {
        $usuariosBuilder = $usuariosBuilder->where('Usuarios.nome', 'like', '%'.Input::get('Usuario_nome').'%');
    }

    if(Input::has('Usuario_est_id'))
    {
        $usuariosBuilder = $usuariosBuilder->where('Usuarios.est_id', '=', Input::get('Usuario_est_id'));
    }

    if(Input::has('Usuario_cidade'))
    {
        $usuariosBuilder = $usuariosBuilder->where('Usuarios.cidade', 'like', '%'.Input::get('Usuario_cidade').'%');
    }

    if(Input::has('Usuario_status'))
    {
        if(Input::get('Usuario_status') == 1)
        {
            $usuariosBuilder = $usuariosBuilder->whereNull('Usuarios.deleted_at');
        }
        elseif(Input::get('Usuario_status') == 2)
        {
            $usuariosBuilder = $usuariosBuilder->onlyTrashed();
        }
    }

    $usuarios = $usuariosBuilder->paginate();

    $estados = Estado::orderBy('uf')->lists('uf', 'est_id');

    return view('usuarios.index', compact('usuarios', 'estados'));
}
```

Fica ai a dica pra quem passar pelo mesmo problema.