# Utilizar 'WHERE' se valor for diferente de 'NULL' num sistema de pesquisa

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estou tentando fazer um simples sistema de pesquisa com alguns campos de texto:

```
$nome = $request->nome;
$email = $request->email;
$bairro = $request->bairro;

$request = Contato::where('nome', 'like', $nome)
    ->where('email', 'like', $email)
    ->where('bairro', 'like', $bairro)
    ->paginate(15);
```

O problema é que alguns campos podem ficar vazios retornando valor null e o mysql  não busca nada.
Dá pra perceber o problema pq eu tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
tabelaTeste

id | nome | email | bairro
1    aaaa   null     null 
2    bbbb   null     null 
3    cccc   null     null
```

E se eu escrever no campo nome:'aaaa' e deixar os outros vazios, nada é retornado. Se eu comentar as linhas dos outros 'where()' e deixar apena o nome, ele funciona normalmente.

**Outra coisa,** vai ter diversos campos.

Comment: Se você chamar duas vezes o metodo where, é equivalente a um fazer um AND na query. Recomendo usar orWhere().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amigo, sugiro utilizar o `whereSub` do Laravel para fazer tal operação. Ele é chamado internamente quando você utiliza um `where` com uma `Closure`.

Costumo fazer isso para fazer condições para o `Where` numa pesquisa, pois como a lógica está amarrada dentro da `Closure`, consigo manter uma boa organização. Assim, você pode fazer várias condições para sua consulta sem ter dores de cabeça por conta de inúmeras condições

Exemplo:

```
$callbackSearch = function ($query) use($request)
{
    if ($request->has('nome'))
    {
        $query->where('nome', 'like', $request->get('nome'));
    }

    if ($request->has('email'))
    {
        $query->where('email', 'like', $request->get('email'));
    }

    // E assim por diante
};

Contato::where($callbackSearch)->paginate(15);
```

O método `has` de `Illuminate\Http\Request` se encarregará de verificar se existe algum valor para aquele input. Se não houver, inteligentemente um trecho da condição `where` não é montada;  porém se houver, aí sim haverá a consulta pelo termo.

Para todos os que querem criar um sistema de buscas no `Laravel`, eu aconselharia fazer dessa forma, pois "amarrar" a lógica da consulta dentro de uma `Closure` vai evitar a poluição do escopo com várias variáveis e ifs soltos, fora da função anônima.

Por exemplo, essa lógica sem a Closure ficaria feia para caramba, assim:

```
$query = Contato::newQuery();

if ($request->has('nome'))
{
    $query->where('nome', 'like', $request->get('nome'));
}

if ($request->has('email'))
{
    $query->where('email', 'like', $request->get('email'));
}

$contato = $query->paginate(15);
```

No último trecho da sua pergunta, você cita que quer fazer essa lógica com  vários campos. A minha sugestão é, para você não repetir a lógica que citei no primeiro exemplo, é você criar uma lista de campos onde quer consultar e, utilizam o método `Request::only`, você especificar os campos possíveis para consulta ao banco. Você irá percorrer o `array` gerado pelo método `only` com um `foreach` e, dentro dele, fará uma verificação se o valor do campo listado é vazio e, então, fazer a consulta, caso o valor não seja vazio.

Exemplo:

```
$callbackSearch = function ($query) use($request)
{

    $campos = ['nome', 'email', 'telefone', 'endereco'];

    foreach ($request->only($campos) as $campo => $valor)
    {
        $valor && $query->where($campo, 'like', $valor);
    }

};
```

Veja como ficou dinâmico. Se você adicionar mais um elemento no `array $campos`, terá uma nova condição adicionada, novinha em folha.

Note que no exemplo eu utilizei uma expressão condicional simplificada:

```
  $valor && $query->where($campo, 'like', $valor);
```

Se você ficou confuso quando ao significado, eu explico: É a mesma coisa que fazer um `if`. Porém, como só quero executar algo, então não "perco tempo" usando chaves e quebras de linhas. Esse pequeno trecho poderia ser escrito das seguintes formas:

```
if ($valor) $query->where($campo, 'like', $valor);

if ($valor) {
    $query->where($campo, 'like', $valor);
}

if ($valor != '') {
   $query->where($campo, 'like', $valor);
}
```

Só quero que entenda que quis diminuir o código :).

Espero que isso ajude!

Comment: Incrível! Funcionou perfeitamente e vai me ajudar em outras situações que tinha dúvida tbm, muito obrigado pela ótima explicação.