# Como Filtrar Vários Campos na Consulta?

Tags: laravel

Estou precisando fazer um filtro em uma consulta no Laravel.

Como posso fazer isso da melhor maneira ? Por exemplo, tenho na minha página uma consulta e quero fazer uns filtros nela. Para isso tenho uma coluna que possui algumas opções de filtros.

Como que eu faria isso no código ? Eu pensei assim:

```
if($string)
   $consulta = Model::where('nome', 'like', '%'.$consulta.'%');

if($numero)
   $consulta = Model::where('matricula', '=', $numero);

if($outro)
   $consulta = Model::where('outro', 'like', '%'.$outro.'%');
```

E depois no final eu faria a consulta. Tem algum jeito melhor ?

Comment: Em codeigniter eu faria dessa forma ai que você propos, eu achei a forma mais sensata

Comment: Acho que esse modelo está bom, mas tenho uma questão: em que casos é que entraria no ultimo `if($outro)`? Nessa estrutura que mostrou porque não faz com `else if..`, não a necessidade de fazer as restantes verificações depois de uma retornar `True`... `$consulta` vai ser sempre a ultima condição em que entra

Comment: É só um exemplo que eu deixei para não aumentar o código na minha pergunta, mas pode ser qualquer filtro. Cidade, Bairro... Sexo...

Comment: Acho que está a fazer bem o que é suposto

Comment: Essa pergunta parece ser duplicada, respondi isso aqui um dia desses

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Laravel - Utilizar 'WHERE' se valor for diferente de 'NULL'](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127107/laravel-utilizar-where-se-valor-for-diferente-de-null)

Comment: @AndréBaill acho que indepentende de ser Codeigniter ou Laravel, a lógica é a mesma. E a simplificação também deve ser a mesma. Não parece ser sensato encher o código de ifs, que vão verificar a mesma coisa, mas para valores diferentes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim é possível fazer isso utilizando o método `where(function(){})` da seguinte forma:

Para o **Laravel 4.2**

```
$consulta = Model::where(function($query) use($string, $numero, $outro) {

     if($string)
         $query->where('nome', "like", "%{$consulta}%");

     if($numero)
         $query->where('matricula', '=', $numero);

      if($outro)
         $query->where('outro', "like", "%{$outro}%"); 
})
->paginate(20);
```

ou

```
$consulta = Model::where(function($query) {

         if(Input::has('consulta'))
             $consulta = Input::get('consulta'); 
             $query->where('nome', "like", "%{$consulta}%");

         if(Input::has('matricula'))
             $numero = Input::get('matricula');
             $query->where('matricula', '=', $numero);

          if(Input::has('outro'))
             $outro = Input::get('outro');
             $query->where('outro', "like", "%{$outro}%"); 
    })
   ->paginate(20);
```

para o **laravel 5.2**

```
$consulta = Model::where(function($query) use($request) {

         if($request->has('consulta'))
             $consulta = $request->consulta; 
             $query->where('nome', "like", "%{$consulta}%");

         if($request->has('matricula'))
             $numero = $request->matricula;
             $query->where('matricula', '=', $numero);

          if($request->has('outro'))
             $outro = $request->outro;
             $query->where('outro', "like", "%{$outro}%"); 
    })
    ->paginate(20);
```

Answer (score 3):

Petter, se a lógica da consulta vai repetir, não tem por que encher "a parada" de `if`. Recomendo que você simplifique seu código encapsulando a lógica da consulta dentro de um loop.

Por exemplo, você quer que os campos `primeiro_nome`, `email` e `sobrenome` sejam pesquisados com `LIKE` e `nivel_id`, `idade` e `curso` sejam pesquisados com o operador `=`.

Você não precisaria fazer vários `ifs`, mas poderia fazer um foreach e aplicar a lógica lá dentro.

```
$callback = function ($query) use($request) {

    $likes = ['primeiro_nome', 'email', 'sobrenome'];

    foreach ($request->only($campos_like) as $name => $value)
    {
        $value && $query->where($name, 'LIKE', "%{$value}%");
    }


    $equals = ['nivel_id', 'idade', 'curso'];

    foreach ($request->only($campos_equal) as $name => $value) {

        $value && $query->where([$name => $value]);
    }

};

Usuario::orderBy('primeiro_nome')->where($calback)->paginate(15)->appends($request->all());
```

Observe que não é necessário encher o código de `if`. Se você puder simplificar, sempre simplifique.

Talvez você esteja se perguntando: "Mas aonde estão os ifs"?

Se observar bem, eu substituí o `if` pela expressão `$value && $query->where(...)`. Costumo fazer isso quando quero simplificar um `if`. Mas não vou entrar em muitos detalhes, pois já respondi isso antes :)

*Refatorar vale a pena se a alma não é pequena!*

[image: Refatorar vale a pena se a alma não é pequena!]